# Laravel select subquery

Tags: php, subquery, laravel-5.1

I'm rather stuck trying to figure out how I can run this as a single query from the database rather than fetching the results using one query then executing the other.

```
$query->whereIn('page_user_id', Staff::lists('staff_id'));
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query->join('staff', 'staff.staff_id', '=', 'user.page_user_id')->get();
```

I think this will help.
For reference `http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries`

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that's three queries not one

Comment: @Shard can you please send me full query So I can provide you correct solution.

Comment: I could but the query builder is 150+ lines long and likely wouldn't help you come to a solution. I basically don't want to have to fetch the data Staff::all()->lists('staff_id') then query it. I want a select subquery within my whereIn that deals with the results all in one query from the database.

Comment: ok, then you can use laravel join's $query->join('staff', 'staff.staff_id', '=', 'user.page_user_id')->get(); (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries)

Comment: Perfect dude, put that as an answer so I can tick it